# Firestore daily quota going wild

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, cloud, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an Angular app using the Firestore database.
While developing I would normally get under 100 API calls per day, looking at the 'Cloud Firestore API Calls'.

But it seems like something changed and I now already have 4000 calls in a few hours today.

I have found that just by clicking around a few times in the tables (in the Firebase Console under the Database tab) i get around 100 calls. And keep in mind I only have 5 tables, with around 5 rows in each.

The app runs locally, and I'm not accessing it. Rules are set up for the database.

It makes no sense to me, that just by viewing *one* of the tables with five rows, I can get 20 API calls.

Anyone got any input? :)

Comment: For input we need your code input.

Comment: The calls happen even when I'm not accessing the app. But just from browsing the tables in the Firebase Console.